# Javascript function print var in div

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

Trying to pass a variable to a function as a parameter of my function and have this function print the value of a global variable in a specific

```
var desc1 = "apple description";
var desc2 = "bananna description";
var desc3 = "orange description";


  function showDesc(arg) {
    var myDesc = arg;
    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = myDesc; 
  }
```

```
<div onclick="showDesc('desc1')">Apples</div>
<div onclick="showDesc('desc2')">Bannans</div>
<div onclick="showDesc('desc3')">Oranges</div>

<div id="description"></div>
```

Trying to make the value of desc1 show in  when clicking on Apples, and show value of desc2 and likewise.

Currently, it is only printing "desc1" when clicking on "Apples" and "desc2" when clicking on "Bananas"

Comment: specify clearly what do you want to do and what is done

Comment: It works fine, https://jsfiddle.net/r6309eq8/#&togetherjs=VKQoP4ACR0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the 'desc1' and 'desc2' etc as strings into the function - you need to consider these as references. The easiest way is to create an object literal and use the passed in argument to select the chosen description from the object literal.

Also - you should be using buttons to handle the clicks -

```js
const descriptions = {
  apple: "Apple description",
  banana: "Bananna description",
  orange: "Orange description"
}


  function showDesc(type) {
    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = descriptions[type]; 
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="showDesc('apple')">Apples</button>
<button type="button" onclick="showDesc('banana')">Bannans</button>
<button type="button" onclick="showDesc('orange')">Oranges</button>

<hr/>

<div id="description"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was missing something. JS is not my first language (normally over in Php and SQL), but just couldn't wrap my mind around it. Thanks so much.